Write pandas DataFrame into a sheet of an `.ods` file without changing the rest? (python)
Suppose I have a pandas.DataFrame called df and an open spreadsheet file file.ods with a sheet mysheet. What is the standard way of writing df to mysheet in file without changing file any other way? We'd want the sheet to contain nothing except the column names in the first row, and the columns beneath them.
I know that we can load all the sheets in file and then change only mysheet and rewrite all those sheets back to a new file which replaces file.ods, but this is not clean, is inefficient (especially if there are a lot of other sheets), and possibly unstable since we'd have to make sure that we also read and rewrite all the additional data and metadata stored in file such as perhaps formatting, macros, and other things I don't know about.
Is there a simple clean way to just overwrite one sheet in an .ods file based on a pandas.DataFrame?
